# Mac Os Catalina prevents jar app to folder

Tags: java, macos, macos-catalina

I have a .app on mac that launches a jar via a sh script.   This means that the app itself is just lunching a jar then the app is no longer running as the jar starts.

The Jar requires access to the launching users Desktop, but in Catalina due to new security restrictions the desktop is blocked.  Anyway to trigger in java a mac alert that allows the user to grant access?  This is the best approach due to if you go to privacy and whitelist to full folder access the user can only add the app, not the jar/java jre which is what i believe the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to figure it out.  My app launcher was a sh script that ran an exec java ...  so basically bc i wanted to use my included framework i launched from java bin folder in the .app using an exec command in a shell script that.

I changed to just running the command line and setting the icon without exec, so in essence java launched like it would have if i executed out of terminal .  By doing thus catalina recognized the folder access and prompted for access properly.